# Async/Await in WPF LOB application: is it worth the added complexity?

Tags: wpf, architecture, async-await

Consider a basic WPF line-of-business application where the server and clients both run on the local network. The server simply exposes a Web API which the clients (running on desktop computers) call into. The UI would consist of CRUD-style screens with buttons to trigger calls to the server.

In my original version of the app none of these UI operations were asynchronous; the UI would freeze for the duration of the call. But nobody complained about the UI becoming unresponsive, nor did anyone notice; the calls were typically less than a quarter second. On the rare occasion if the network connection was down, the UI would freeze for as long as it took for the operation to timeout, which was the only time that eyebrows were raised.

Now that I’ve begun implementing async/await for all server calls, it has quickly become apparent that I have a new issue on my hands: the complexities of dealing with re-entrancy and cancellation. Theoretically, now the user can click on any button while a call is already in progress. They can initiate operations that conflict with the pending one. They can inadvertently create invalid application states. They can navigate to a different screen or log out. Now all these previously impossible scenarios have to be accounted for.

It seems like I’ve opened up a Pandora’s Box.

I contrast this to my old non-async design, where the UI would lock-up for the duration of the server call, and the user could simply *not click on anything*. This guaranteed that they couldn’t foul anything up, and thus allowed the application code to remain at least 10x simpler.
So what is really gained by all this modern approach of async-everywhere? I bet if the user compared the sync and async versions side-by-side, they wouldn’t even notice any benefit from the async version; the calls are so quick that the busy indicator doesn’t even have time to render. 
It just seems like a whole tonne of extra work, complexity, harder-to-maintain code, for very little benefit.  I hear the KISS principle calling…

So what am I missing? In an LOB application scenario, what are the benefits of async warrant the extra work?

Comment: the usual way you handle the situation you are describing is that while the task is running the command's can execute is false, meaning the command can't be duplicated until completed (complete meaning success, fail, error etc) also rememberer if your MVVM structure is correct data access is handled in the M so from your V end there should be little (if any) difference between Sync and ASync

Comment: I'm developing a large WPF MVVM LOB application for the last 11 years and I can say: Unfortunately we don't use async/await because it would be way too much work for us to change our existing large codebase so that each and every method up to the GUI is using async. But we do have a few workers to enable a fully async CQRS-like style. So in essence we aren't using async/await but we have our own fluent methods like `doSomething.ContinueWhenError(...)`. For the most part we are using `TaskCompletionSource` and `CancellationTokenSource` in combination with `Task.Run()`. And that's not so bad.

Comment: Another reason why we can't change our large codebase so easily to async/await is that our ViewModels are very constructor-based. You can't mark constructors with `async` so we can't use `await` in them. And unfortunately we cannot change our whole architecture to a method-based approach so easily. So we'll probably never use async/await but we don't have a single action in our application that will block the GUI because we enforce the asynchronous execution within the GUI service layer. Reentrance was never a problem for us because we don't need the dispatcher in our ViewModel continuations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is really gained by all this modern approach of async-everywhere?

You already know the answer: the primary benefit of `async` for UI apps is responsiveness. (The primary benefit of `async` on the server side is scalability, but that doesn't come into play here).

If you don't need responsiveness, then you don't need `async`. In your scenario, it sounds like you may get away with that approach, and that's fine.

For software that is *sold*, though - and in particular, mobile applications - the standard is higher. Apps that freeze are so '90s. And mobile platforms *really* dislike apps that freeze, since you're freezing the entire screen instead of just a window - at least one platform I know of will execute your application and drop network acess, and if it freezes, it's automatically rejected from the app store. Freezing simply isn't acceptable for modern applications.

But like I said, for your specific scenario, you may get away without going `async`.

Comment: When you say that "apps that freeze are so '90s", first of all I agree with you. But haven't we replaced it with a modern version of freezing: the ubiquitous modal busy indicator (or whatever it's called)? Sure, the UI thread isn't blocked and the OS is happy, and technically the user can drag the window around, but if they cannot click anything within the app until the long-running operation is complete, isn't that somewhat equivalent to freezing? Again, from a user perspective, what is gained by all the async complexity under the hood?

Comment: @BCA: A modal busy indicator is the least-viable solution. It's the thing to put in first just to get off the ground. Asynchronous UIs also allow: incremental downloads (scroll down to load more - but you can scroll up while those are loading), partial "light-up"s (the left panel loads before the right; you can interact with the left as soon as it loads), work queues (see all active ops with their progress, cancel individual ones).